# Android JUnit test for OpenGL code gets NoClassDefFound : android/opengl/Matrix

Tags: android, opengl-es, junit

I have a little Android application that uses OpenGl. This project works fine.

Then, I made a new JUnit project to test the first one.  The test works fine if no OpenGL code is reached...  But if I use some OpenGL classes (for example, android/opengl/Matrix), the test throw a NoClassDefFoundError.  I re-made the JUnit project many times (in JUnit3, JUnit4...), and I had this error all the times.

I look in the class path, etc... in the two projects, and I don't found any difference.  I look in the manifest file too, and search internet... and nobody seems have any problem with opengl and JUnit :P

Any suggestions?  thanks!